# Declare template<typename Foo<T>> instead of template<typename T>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a `template<typename T> class Foo`.
I want to declare a function that can return any kind of Foo. I would do it like this: `template<typename T> Foo<T> bar();`
But this means that I have to use it like this: `Foo<SomeConcreteT> f = bar<SomeConcreteT>();`, and `SomeConcreteT` can be very long and clunky and annoying to have to type out.
I do, however, have some

```
using AppleFoo = Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>;
using BananaFoo = Foo<SomethingElseForBananas>;
// ...
```

I would prefer to call bar like this: `AppleFoo f = bar<AppleFoo>();`, so I don't have to type out `ABunchOfStuffForApples` all the time, and conceptually, `AppleFoo` telly the reader more about what's supposed to happen here than `ABunchOfStuffForApples` does.

I can do it by adding `using TType = T` inside `Foo` and a helper function like this:

```
template<typename F>
F bar()
{
    return bar<F::TType>();
}
```

But this is ugly and error-prone (e.g. calling `bar<SomethingThatIsNotAFoo>()`).

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?
And is there, more generally, a way of testing whether some type is a `SomethingKnown<SomethingUnknown>`, e.g. in a `static_assert`?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `auto f = bar<AppleFoo::type>()`?

Comment: maybe the quesiton is more clear if you show the code instead of describing it. When you say "is ugly and error-prone" dont assume that it is obvious what you mean. "ugly" is purely subjective, and I also dont see what you mean with "error-prone"

Comment: @Caleth Not too shabby. It's much better than typing out `ABunchOfStuffForApples`. But not quite like just typing only `AppleFoo`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, it's subjective. The point is to avoid what I percieve as uglyness. It does not have to be anything specific. Just assume something that you would find too annoying to type out every time. The point is just to avoid it.
For the error-prone-ness I gave an example. If you call bar with a type that is not actually a Foo of something, you can get very obscure error messages that might not be entirely obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretend to have return-type deduction, by having `bar` be a non-template that returns a proxy with a `operator Foo<T>`

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    /* ... */
};

namespace detail {
    struct bar_t {
        template <typename T>
        operator Foo<T>() { /* current implemenation of bar */ }
    };
}

detail::bar_t bar() { return {}; }

using AppleFoo = Foo<struct Apple>;

int main() {
    AppleFoo f = bar();
}
```

Comment: Creative use of that operator, but I see a few problems. 1. `auto f = bar(); f.doIt();` (where `doIt` is a function of `Foo`) won't work, which breaks the illusion. 2. I now have to maintain two separate source code locations for `bar` 3. I am not sure how this works if `bar` is supposed to be declared inside `Foo`.

Comment: @NikoO 1 is a problem, but there's *no mention* of a type in that snippet. 2. you have a trivial implementation of `bar`, and a differently named `detail::bar_t::operator Foo`. 3. You can put `bar` anywhere

Comment: 1. Ah, my bad. I misunderstood your code. (I actually considered calling out the obscurity of the code, but then again, that's C++ in general.) Considering this, this approach is not ideal because I want to use the result of `bar<AppleFoo>()` in more complex expressions where it must already have the correct type. I would have to write something like `(AppleFoo)bar()`, which is not great. 2. In this case, yes, but consider the case where bar takes parameters. If I want to add another, I have to change two places in the code. 3. Sorry, I meant if the original `bar` is inside Foo.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a traits to know if it is a Foo and extract its template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_foo : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_foo<Foo<T>> : std::true_type
{
    using type = T;
};
```

and then

```
template<typename FOO>
FOO bar()
{
    static_assert(is_foo<FOO>::value);

    using T = typename is_foo<FOO>::type;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I am currently using something very similar to this in conjunction with `enable_if` on the helper `bar` function. It's a somewhat well-working idea, so have an upvote! I was hoping, though, to find something simpler/terser.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, if you can change calling syntax, you might pass a tag, something along

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};
```

and then

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(tag<Foo<T>>)
{
    return bar<T>();
}
```

with usage similar to

```
using AppleFoo = Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>;

auto bar1 = bar(tag<AppleFoo>{});
auto bar2 = bar(tag<Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>>{});
// auto is AppleFoo and so Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>
```

If you dislike tag in interface, you can still use it as implementation:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar_impl(tag<Foo<T>>)
{
    // implementation, such as return Foo<T>(); 
}

// Possibly other specialization for Foo<std::vector<T>>, Foo<int>, .. 

template<typename T>
auto bar()
{
    return bar_impl(tag<T>{});
}
```

with usage

```
using AppleFoo = Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>;

auto bar1 = bar<AppleFoo>();
auto bar2 = bar<Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>>();
// auto is AppleFoo and so Foo<ABunchOfStuffForApples>
```

Comment: This obscures the purpose of `bar` quite a bit, I would say. Having the type look like a parameter is weird. I'm not a fan, but it's an option.

Comment: Function template without deducing type doesn't allow specialization/overload. Tag allows that easily. You can use tag for implementation  (and so extract template parameter easily), and then have `template <typename T>auto bar() { return bar_impl(tag<T>{}); }` for public interface.